On knowing nothing
Socrates said:

I know that I do not know. (1)

When I constructed a, what I thought was a similar statement:
"There are no absolute truths, other than this one." (2)
I got responses that, the notion of absolute truth is not a well defined one, and thus that my statement also has some flaws with its meaning, or some other problems with logic or the syntax or meaning of our language, etc...
My question is:
Does Socrates' statement (1) encounter also the same problems as mine statement (2) or is it different in some sense and doesn't have such problems because he constructed it more carefully or something?

You can be certain that you exist. In order to get further the basic axiomatic assumption needs to be that you exist in something, a world (for want of a better word). I.e. Being-in-the-world as the basic state of Dasein

@ChrisDegnen But one can even question his/hers own existence, right?

I addressed that here: consciousness is a fundamental? : I.e. "whatever may be asserted, and in whatever sense, this asserting and thinking is always an "I think." Thinking is always an "I think," ego cogito. Therein lies: I am, sum. Cogito, sum — this is the highest certainty lying immediately in the proposition as such." (Modern Science, Metaphysics, and Mathematics, p. 278)

@ChrisDegnen Hm, very interesting. So just by the mere fact of "thinking", I can say "I think". Seems like a pretty watertight statement. Even if I try to disprove it by saying: "But maybe I don't know that I am thinking and what thinking really is." I am essentially still in some sense thinking about it hence just fortifying your statement.

Yup, exactly. :-)

@ChrisDegnen Although it is a strong statement, it only proves the existence of "you" the thinking thing, I don't see how it connects to the rest of the reality. Maybe there is only you in reality and nothing else. It doesn't give some connection to something outside of the subject.

Yes, Descartes hit that problem, see dualism. The minimal workable assumption is to start with being-in-the-world as the "unitary phenomenon", partly justified by the rationale that if one exists one must exist somewhere, but also because one's mind is cultural. "In clarifying Being-in-the-world we have shown that a bare subject without a world never 'is' proximally, nor is it ever given. And so in the end an isolated "I" without Others is just as far from being proximally given." Others

The interesting thing is, (and this is what Heidegger is really interested in), is what is the 'existence' of Dasein. Dasein is a being, but what does 'being' mean, as in 'existing'. This is not the objective type of existence of things which exist objectively (over against Dasein, as ob-ject'ed : 'thrown against' the subject Dasein). The 'activity' of being which Dasein does in existing is actually indefinable and analytically indeterminate, which is pretty amazing to figure out (or follow through the reasoning) e.g. What existence is?

According to Plato, Socrates said: "I seem, then, in just this little thing to be wiser than this man at any rate, that what I do not know I do not think I know either." This has been paraphrased, into the form you quote. Socrates is framing a description of knowledge as being tentative, as scientific knowledge is now held to be. Discussed here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/75734/what-is-the-literal-meaning-of-the-only-thing-that-i-know-is-that-i-know-nothin/81607#81607

@ChrisDegnen -- You presume that thoughts are fundamental.  But as detailed in Thinking Fast and Slow, the vast majority of our thinking is unconscious.  While there may in principle still be a thinker doting the fast processing, we actually don't know from direct acquaintance that there was even a  "thought" for this unconscious processing.  Do you consider there to be thoughts in our digital machines?  And how would we know either way?

@Dcleve Any unconscious thoughts (if there are such) would be included in the inscrutable concept of Being, (i.e. "We can infer only that ‘Being’ cannot have the character of an entity." SZ 4). Science establishes facts and scientific reality by virtue of observers' consciousness examining nature, so for this Being-in-the-world would be more fundamental than consciousness. Glancing at 'Thinking, Fast And Slow' – . . .

. . chapter 19: The Illusion of Understanding would cover the 'intuitive understanding' of being, but in trying to actually explain Being one becomes unstuck. OTOH, trying to explain 'existence' via science also meets significant hurdles. Existence is inscrutable all round. Ordinarily, 'being' seems obvious until one realises so much is going on invisibly to bring the show to life. Heidegger sketches out the modalities of human existence in order to shed light on the meaning of existence in general.


The following fragment is handed down from the Greek philosopher
Xenophanes at about 550 BCE:

“But as for certain truth, no man has known it, Nor will he know it;
neither of the gods Nor yet of all the things of which I speak. And
even if by chance he were to utter The perfect truth, he would himself
not know it; For all is but a woven web of guess.” (Fragment B34)

The fragment has often been quoted by the modern philosopher Karl
Popper. The epistemological positions agrees with your point of
view.

Popper agreed with Xenophanes and draw the consequence to
abandon - at least in science - the search for final irrefutable
knowledge. Instead scientific theories are hypotheses which have
been confirmed and not yet refuted. Scientific knowledge remains
hypothetical.

The viewpoint that there is no ultimate justification of general
knowledge has been illustrated by Popper’s follower Hans Albert by
the  Muenchhausen trilemma.

The quote from Socrates has to be translated more precisely: “I know
that I do not know.” Socrates emphasizes that there are many things
he does not know. But he does not pride himself to know everything
like many experts he took to task on Athen’s market place.



What would you say if Socrates was here today. What school of thought would he be most fond of and what philosopher? Could his scio nihil scire be considered epistemological skepticism?

@User198 The answer to your final question: I imagine that Socrates would call for intellectual modesty. At most we are specialists in a certain branch of knowledge. That’s not necessarily a prompt to epistemological skepticism. - Concerning your first question: Taking Plato’s early dialogues as guide Socrates possibly would call for clear definitions of abstract concepts.

A somewhat pithier and more nuanced version of your quote was offhandedly made (by the Joan Campbell character) in the TV show Covert Affairs, very first line in the script at https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=15124 To wit, "Whatever you think you know, it is not the whole truth." Pretty good one, Joan.

The Dutch 19th century writer Multatuli (the first to vehemently criticize Dutch colonialism in Indonesia) once wrote this variantion on the Liar: "Perhaps nothing is completely true, and even that isn't."

The two statements are very different, and it isn't even related to the "absolute" part of it. The latter, 2, clearly presents a positive and unsubstantiated axiom. It is also speaking broadly about external and real and infinite set of things and presenting a categorical claim. While it might be possible to conceive of a world in which that statement is true, we have no justification that it is true, and it would seem that it was chosen arbitrarily. Therefore, it would be uncompelling to accept it as true, and it certainly isn't something that can be affirmed from typical models for knowledge.
The former, 1, presents a very limited factual claim about the speaker's mental state, merely stating that he does not know. At the time, there were not such rigorous models describing what it means to "know", but intuitively we see knowledge as somehow being a reliable tool which is in some way related to a reliable method of justification. The speaker can consider several things which he might suspect he knows only to discover that he could not reliably know them, and this investigation could itself be seen as justification of a sort that is more reliable than for his other attempts at knowledge. Thus, his degree of confidence in the first know is greater to some significant amount than in the second set of "know"s. Since it is speaking merely about his mental state, rather than an external state, the speaker can be seen as a sufficiently reliable source of information and it is from a sufficiently limited scope that he might be capable of making such a claim.
I also want to point out that they are different in that 1 is talking about knowledge and 2 is talking about truths. Truth is, in popular models, a component of knowledge, but the inverse is not true. In other words, even if we cannot possibly know a thing, that doesn't affect whether or not that thing is true. Therefore, knowledge is a much more achievable bar to affirm than truth.
1 is also a starting point where 2 is a stopping point. 1 invites us to attempt to try to find things which we can know, while 2 provides a hard stop in finding any truth (and therefore, probably knowledge).
We simply cannot know that there are not absolute truths, and if there are, we cannot know that we could not somehow know them, or at least some of them. Positive claims need to be supported. We can be aware, however, that we lack any method to naively arrive at consistent conclusions. In other words, if we do have some capacity to know absolute truth, it isn't obvious. This is different than stating that we cannot know anything, and it certainly isn't making a claim that there is nothing true.

We have to be careful to keep ontology and epistemology separate. The phrase "There are no absolute truths" implies an ontological claim — an assertion about facts — which is why adding "except this one" feels paradoxical or problematic. But the phrase "I know that I do not know" is an epistemological claim - an assertion about knowledge — which merely suggests that one knows that knowledge has limits.
Unfortunately, the term 'truth' doesn't distinguish between experiential truths and inferential truths, which causes endless confusion.

Socrates used this phrase in his Apology, that is, in his defense against accusations that he had corrupted the youth of Athens with his impiety.
I don't think it had any particular epistemelogical purpose. He just used it as a clever device to solve the paradox of how the oracle at Delphi could have judged him the wisest of all men. He then concluded that if he knew that he knew nothing then he knew just that much more than anybody else who knew nothing. At least he knew that he knew nothing. No wonder the trial ended with the death penalty. You don't call people stupid.
Your second question: or is it different in some sense and doesn't have such problems because he constructed it more carefully or something?
Yes: "For I was conscious that I knew practically nothing..." (Plato, Apology 22d, translated by Harold North Fowler, 1966).
Practically nothing is not nothing.

In logic, truth is a set of judgements that are logically consistent, while falsehood is the counterpart set, that where judgements are logically inconsistent.
"There are no absolute truths, other than this one."
The adjective "absolute" has no meaning aside truth, it is like saying she's absolutely pregnant, she's very pregnant, she's excessively pregnant. Either she is pregnant, or not, no need for adjectives. In the same way, something is true if it is logically consistent with the truth set, or not.
So, this would become "there are no truths other than this one", which is evidently a false dichotomy fallacy, since it has this form: because this is true, all other judgements are true. So, this can be discarded
Or else, this might become "This is true", a tautology which has no issues.
The confusion comes from the adjective.
"I know that I do not know"
"I know that I do not know" has the logical form K(I) = Not(K(I)), which is a contradiction, so this would not lie in the truth group. However, the intention is rhetoric, not literal: the more I know, the less I understand I know. It should not be taken literally.

Okay, so both statements talk about knowing and truth, but they do it differently. Socrates' famous "I know that I know nothing" isn't really about claiming anything is absolutely true. It's more like saying, "I realize how much I don't know." It's about being humble and open to learning. It's not a paradox because it's a personal statement about his own understanding, not a grand rule about the universe.
Your statement, "There are no absolute truths, other than this one," is trickier. It's like saying, "This is the only exception to the rule that there are no exceptions!" See the problem? It trips over itself. If it's true, then it has to be false because it claims to be an absolute truth. And if it's false, well, then maybe there are other absolute truths, but it still doesn't fix the initial contradiction.
So.. both statements kind of loop back to themselves. But Socrates is talking about his knowledge, while you're talking about the idea of truth in general.
Socrates isn't saying anything is definitely true or false about the world. He's just talking about what he knows. Your statement, on the other hand, tries to make a big, universal rule, and that's where the trouble starts, especially with that "except this one" bit.
Your statement gets tangled up because it contradicts itself. Socrates', even though it sounds a little weird at first, doesn't actually break any logic rules.

[Thinking that statement (1) is partially correct] You can extend statement (1) (E.g.: "I know that I know only a few things.”)  I mean, ANYONE can think that statement (1) is partially correct.
But you cannot extend your statement (2)  like this. You locked all the doors 'mentioning' that there is 'only' one  absolute truth (that even you are not sure of).
No one is sure that statement 2 is even absolutely true.  Since it is doubtful, NO ONE can think that statement (2) is even partially correct.
Your statement faces more problems than that of Socrates'.
There is humility in Socrates' statement. So, it can be used to focus on oneself. But I cannot see such humility in your statement.  Therefore, it cannot be used for introspection.
The former touches the WISDOM of both the listener and the speaker; whereas the latter 'tries' to touch only the INTELLECT.

...Is it different in some sense and doesn't have such problems
because he constructed it more carefully or something?

Yes. The above explanations reveal that.

Hi. I did not use the word "only" ? And the statement: " I know that I know only a few things.” seems rather dull.

@User198: I have corrected my remarks.

A sound approach to this type of issues, based on natural (and not formal) language and using the tools of philosophival analysis can be boorowed from Alexandre Koyré's essay: The Liar (Philosophy and Phenomenological Research, 1946):

At first sight, it appears that the assertion "I am lying" is meaningful.
This error arises because, in the last analysis and in general, language expresses
our thought in a very imperfect and incomplete manner. [...] Consequently,
in order to interpret the words we hear we have to reconstitute and to restore
the whole of the intended meaning. [...] Accordingly, when someone says "I am lying" we interpret this utterance, we substitute, we add, we qualify. We understand the sentence as meaning either "I have been lying" or, "I sometimes lie" or "I often lie," which can be true or false and, in any case, is a perfectly correct statement;
or even "I am always lying," a judgment of the type of Epimenides, elfcontradictory,
but therefore meaningful.


Yet, the expression "I am lying" means or pretends to mean something
else, something quite different, which does not extend its application to the
past or to the future, but confines itself to the present. This expression
claims to mean "I am lying now, in this moment" or, "It is in this moment
that I am making a false assertion" or, "The assertion that I am making
in this moment is false."

Thus, we have two levels of discourse at play here: the object discourse, i.e. some/all previous statements of Epimenides, and the context discourse: the judgement Epimenides is making about the previous one.
The same for Socrates: the judgment "I know that I do not know" is a context judgment asserting that all previous attempts to achieve "dogmatic" knowledge failed.
But now the philosopher has achieved a new level of understanding: he started to know, he has achieved a solid ground on which to build a new process to achieve knowledge, based on the dialectical approach.
